# npm install command suddenly not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

The commands `npm install` and `npm install <package-name>` are suddenly not working on **Ubuntu 22.04**. I have never experienced this problem before and I have been using npm for years.

I tried reinstalling, purging, removing directories etc. Nothing seems to work.

The terminal just freezes after I hit Enter.

Node 18.12.1
npm 8.19.2

Anyone else that encountered this problem?

Comment: What version of npm/node do you use?

Comment: Node 18.12.1 and npm 8.19.2.

Comment: Only the install command doesn't work? Or is it npm commands in general?

Comment: `npm init` works fine (generates package.json), but `npm install` and `npm outdated` do not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have been solved after I installed nvm.

I completely removed the nodejs installation (including cache etc) and installed nvm from here:

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Then I installed node 16.x by running nvm install 16 (instead of 18, which gave me the problem).

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, with `node js 18.18` and `npm 9.6.7`, and I just updated `node js` to version `20` using:

```bash
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | sudo -E bash -
```

This also updated the `npm` version, and it works fine now. Please note that the above command is going to be deprecated soon.